# Making a new TTPRPG with some mechanics borrowed from DnD5e and PF2e SRD

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-2e, game-design, intellectual-property, indie-rpg

I am making a new TTPRPG for a non-English market. I use many class concepts and mechanics mainly from PF2e and DnD5e SRDs, but not their lore, world settings or named trademarks.

My questions are:

1. Are the SRDs intended to make 3rd-party publications for their systems only?
2. Is it legal that I make an independent TTPRPG with my own world settings and lore, only to use some of the classes and mechanics from the aforementioned SRDs? If so, how would I cite the SRDs as they mention that I cannot have PF2e or DnD5e on my published products?

Comment: I don't believe anyone outside respective publishing houses can objectively answer 1. Do they allow you to do so is objectively answerable, but the *internation* is off topic.

Comment: You are entering a legal minefield; using the rules from two different companies, merging them together, and calling the end result your own. No answer you get from here should be construed as legal advice and if you act on any of it (other that hiring a real lawyer) is setting yourself up for one or more lawsuits. Talk to actual IP lawyers and get real answers.

Comment: @Molot I suspect someone with legal experience developing 3rd party content may have some insight here. I know there are some users here who have published content, whether they will comment I don't know, but it's definitely an issue that many people here know about.

Comment: @Non-human someone with legal experience could tell if it's allowed, but not if the *intention* was for it to be allowed.

Comment: @MivaScott Luckily, both products are licensed under the exact same license. That helps immensely in cutting down on potential weird interactions that require a law degree to sort out. The purpose of licenses is to allow non-lawyers to safely do things; while a lawyer is best, this is not the minefield you suggest.

Comment: @Mołot You're reading too far into it. You don't need to be a mind reader to answer that question, a quote from WotC saying the SRD is for "xyz" is enough.

Answer (score 9):

> Are the SRDs intended to make 3rd-party publications for their systems only?

I don’t know about “intended,” but the 1st edition of Pathfinder was based on the d20 System SRD, derived from the “v.3.5 revised edition” of D&D. Pathfinder was, not, however, labeled as a d20 System product, nor was it compatible with d20 System, but was instead its own (very similar but not quite compatible) system. Since Pathfinder ate D&D’s lunch there for a while, you’d think that if Wizards of the Coast could have sued that problem away, they would have.

More to the point, the [Open Game License 1.0a](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/SRD-OGL_V1.1.pdf), which is the version that both the D&D 5e SRD and Pathfinder 2e are licensed under, says nothing about the purposes for which you use open game content: it only specifies what content is open game content, what you have to do to use it (primarily, include the OGL in your product, clearly label the open game content of other Contributors, clearly label your open game content and your product identity, avoid using anyone else’s product identity, and don’t market your work using the names of any of the Contributors of open game content that you are using).

In general, it is best to check with a lawyer about the specific thing you are aiming to do; it shouldn’t be terribly expensive to have a lawyer read a 2-page license and then answer a few questions about the compatibility of your plans. But what you are aiming to do sounds like it should be no problem whatsoever; I am not a lawyer, certainly not your lawyer, and I don’t know all the details of what you plan to do, but it *sounds like* I’d be comfortable moving forward with your plans without necessarily needing a lawyer involved.

If you don’t get a lawyer involved, though, you’ll want to read the OGL yourself. It’s only 2 pages, and it’s pretty clear, for a license. You’ll want to do this anyway.

Also, for completion’s sake, it might be possible to do what you propose *without* the OGL: game mechanics cannot be copyrighted. What can, and is, copyrighted, are the text, tables, diagrams, and so on *explaining* the mechanics. You need the OGL to use those things. If you were to write a game from scratch, and it just so happened to use some of the same ideas, you would be fine. The problem is that it can be very difficult to separate what we have already learned from some source from our own ideas, and just “putting it in your own words” is **not** sufficient to avoid copyright infringement. Where I feel it’s likely that I’d be comfortable with using the OGL without a lawyer on what you propose, I would not even remotely *consider* attempting an unlicensed work even slightly “inspired by” specific games without consulting one.

Comment: I'll point out that there's already an established precedent by a number of retroclones of previous editions of DnD that show that WotC is unlikely to go after you for one as long as you don't mention DnD.

Comment: @nick012000 Maybe, but those _could_ also be cases of security through obscurity; we can’t _know_ that Wizards was aware of them but chose not to go after them, or if they were just unaware. On the other hand, there is no way they were unaware of Pathfinder, which is their largest competition and is published by a company with which they had a close business relationship with rather recently.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. While I am sure to at least consult with a IP lawyer in the country when the product is later stage where content is mostly finished but still has room to be easily adjusted around, I just want to hear some thoughts from the TTPRPG community. Cheers.